# continuous function and limits

Tags: limits, functions

$h:(-3,3)\setminus{2}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}, x \mapsto \begin{cases} -1& -3<x\leq-2\\ 1-x^2  & -2<x<0\\ \frac{x^2-x-2}{x-2} & 0\leq x <3, x\neq2\end{cases}$

At which points is $h$ continuous and at which points exist limits? 
(Looking at $x=-3,-2,0,2,3$.)

---

for $x>-3: \lim_{x\to -3}=-1$, $x$ can't be $<-3$ and it also can't be $=-3$ because that isn't in the interval but I don't know how to interpret that; I would guess that the limit exists but that $h$ isn't continuous at the point because the point doesn't even exist

for $x<-2: \lim_{x\to -2}=-1$, for $x>-2: \lim_{x\to -2}=-3$; so this definitely means that $h$ isn't continuous at that point and a limit also doesn't exist

for $x<0: \lim_{x\to 0}=1$, for $x>0: \lim_{x\to 0}=1$, for $x=0:1$; this means that the limit exists and that $h$ is continuous

for $x<2$ and $x>2 : \lim_{x\to 2}=-1$, $2$ isn't in the interval so I would make the same guess as I did with $-1$ but this time the limit works from both sides so maybe it's different

$3$ is just the same as $-3$, I basically just need someone to tell me how to interpret this stuff

Comment: It's precisely $lim_{x \to -3^+} h(x)=-1$ since $h$ is not defined at & to the left of $x=-3$

Comment: The word is *continuous* (not *continous*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $h$ as
$$
h(x) = -\mathsf 1_{(-3,-2]}(x) + (1+x)(1-x)\mathsf 1_{(-2,0)}(x) + \left(\frac{x^2-x-2}{x-2}\right)\mathsf 1_{[0,3)\setminus\{2\}}(x).
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to -2^-} h(x) = -1 \ne -3 = \lim_{x\to -2^+}h(x),
$$
so $h$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=-2$. Further,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}h(x) = 1 = \lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x) = h(0),
$$
so $h$ is continuous at $x=0$. Now, since $x^2-x-x = (x-2)(x+1)$, we may rewrite $\frac{x^2-x-2}{x-2} = 1+x$. So
$$
\lim_{x\to 2^-}h(x) = -1 = \lim_{x\to 2^+}h(x),
$$
but $h$ is not defined at $x=2$, so $h$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=2$. As for $x=3$, this is not within the domain of $h$, nor is $h$ defined on a right-neighborhood of $x=3$, so it does not make sense to speak of continuity at that point.

Comment: Can we speak of continuity at points that aren't in the domain like $x=2$

Comment: Technically, no. But we can define $h'(x) = h(x) - \mathsf 1_{\{2\}}(x)$ to make $h'$ a continuous extension of $h$.

Comment: Can we answer the question "Does $h$ have a limit at $-3$?" with yes or no? Or do we just say $\lim_{x\to -3^+}h(x) = -1$. And what about $2$? $2$ isn't defined but the lim approaches from both sides and has the same value.